# Cleanup for the broadcastreceiver tag

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags

This is an attempt to cleanup the [broadcastreceiver](/questions/tagged/broadcastreceiver) tag on stackoverflow. I reviewed the questions that had this tag and the vast majority are related to [android](/questions/tagged/android)(the questions that didn't have the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag were mistagged). The only questions were I'm looking for a second opinion are:

[Sending broadcast with Chrome Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827220/sending-broadcast-with-chrome-extensions) - **Wrong tag?**

[Wireless Data Broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924689/wireless-data-broadcast) - **Wrong tag? Or most likely closed for `Not a real questions`/ duplicate of the question below?**

[Wireless Oneway Broadcast Feasibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892185/wireless-oneway-broadcast-feasibility) - **Wrong tag?**

[Does broadcasting over UDP repeatedly send its packet, or just once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589906/using-c-does-broadcasting-over-udp-repeatedly-send-its-packet-or-just-once) - **Wrong tag? Could be a valid tag in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) questions?**

[Application that receives DVB-H broadcast signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989224/application-that-receives-dvb-h-broadcast-signal) - **Wrong tag? Or most likely closed for `Not a real question?`**

[Qt Network Broadcasting Question: To get sender IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870521/qt-network-broadcasting-question-to-get-sender-ip) - **Wrong tag**?

[iPhone reading a broadcast transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415776/iphone-reading-a-broadcast-transmission) - **Wrong tag?**

+1 question which I didn't managed to find:(.

The wiki for the [broadcastreceiver](/questions/tagged/broadcastreceiver) refers to the Android component, the excerpt is a bit to general and could tempt users to use this tag when they shouldn't(I will try to modify this). 
Also, if the questions above are wrongly tagged maybe the [broadcastreceiver](/questions/tagged/broadcastreceiver) could be merged into the more specific tag [android-broadcastreceiver](/questions/tagged/android-broadcastreceiver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you were missing is [UDP Broadcast Reception Problems with Ubuntu 9.04 but not 8.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130563/udp-broadcast-reception-problems-with-ubuntu-9-04-but-not-8-04), you probably have one of its tags ignored. It was mis-tagged too.

I removed that tag from the questions you list since they were indeed unrelated to the Android component which is clearly what the majority of questions using this tag are about. There are no more [broadcastreceiver](/questions/tagged/broadcastreceiver) questions without the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag right this minute.
I also updated the tag wiki and excerpt to make it clearer that this is an Android component and not a generic term. Hopefully this will help keep things clean going forward.

Note: I'm not a big fan of the [android-superduperfoo](/questions/tagged/android-superduperfoo) or [facebook-socialwonderbar](/questions/tagged/facebook-socialwonderbar) overly-long tags. Unless there's significant ambiguity or tag "pollution", I'd rather leave that one as is.

Comment: The tag wiki entry for Android says to prefer `android-CLASS` tags... it doesn't mention anything about length of the tag.

Comment: I know what you mean though... but I think `android-broadcastreceiver` should definitely get its own "hyphenated tag" given that `android-service`, `android-activity`, `android-intent`, and `android-contentprovider` all get their own too.

Comment: Sure, to disambiguate it works well. But `broadcastreceiver` is well-established. If someone wants to propose a synonym (or if a mod wants to rename it), fine. Anyway, I can do neither, so the point is moot for me, technically.

Comment: TBH, I think Android should just get its own stackexchange site. Then we wouldn't have to worry about hyphenated tags in the first place :)

Comment: Thanks Mat for finding the one missing question and for editing the others (I would have done it myself anyway, I just asked for a second opinion on those questions). As Alex already said, I am for transforming the `broadcastreceiver` tag to the more specific `android-broadcastreceiver` although the new tag would be kind of big visually. I leave it up to a MOD if the transformation makes sense.